# Checking the RTTI

Tags: c++, oop, class, dynamic-cast

I have the following classes and methods:

```
//Base class
class Node {
    public:
        virtual ~Node() {};
        Node() {};
    private:
        // Private things for my implementation.
};

class Element : public Node {
    public:
        // Returns the name of the element.
        const xml::String &name() const {
            return eleName;
        }

        static bool is_Element(const Node *base) {
            Element *p = NULL;
            p = dynamic_cast<Element*>(base);
            return (p!=NULL);
        }

        static const Element *to_Element(const Node *base) {
            return dynamic_cast<Element*>(base);   
        }

    private:
        s_namespace eleNamespace;
        xml::String &eleName;
        // Private things for my implementation.
};
```

Here when I dynamic cast it says the following compile error. How to correct it? One method is to simple remove the `const` of the parameters. But I donot think that is the correct method.

> oops.cpp: In static member function ‘static bool
>   xml::Element::is_Element(const xml::Node*)’: oops.cpp:208:44: error:
>   cannot dynamic_cast ‘base’ (of type ‘const class xml::Node*’) to type
>   ‘class xml::Element*’ (conversion casts away constness) oops.cpp: In
>   static member function ‘static const xml::Element*
>   xml::Element::to_Element(const xml::Node*)’: oops.cpp:213:47: error:
>   cannot dynamic_cast ‘base’ (of type ‘const class xml::Node*’) to type
>   ‘class xml::Element*’ (conversion casts away constness)

Comment: The error says it all: `conversion casts away constness`.

Comment: @chris, yes. So how should I apprach it in a different way?

Comment: Cast it to `const Element*`.  Because casting it to `Element*` casts away the constness.

Comment: @footy Using `dynamic_cast` to find out the dynamic type of an object is usually a sign of bad design. Why do you need to know if your `Node` is an `Element`? You should be able to use an `Element` as though it were a `Node`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but `is_Element` should return `p != NULL`, not `base != NULL`.

Comment: @Flexo Hmm.. Probably not since I Alexander's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks! That was a typo in the question. Not intentional. I fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `dynamic_cast<const Element*>` instead.

You can also make your class const-correct, by implementing two different functions for a const-Argument and a non-const Argument:

```
    static const Element *to_Element(const Node *base) {
        return dynamic_cast<const Element*>(base);   
    }

    static Element *to_Element(Node *base) {
        return dynamic_cast<Element*>(base);   
    }
```

So if the caller has a non-const `Node` he probably also wants a non-const `Element` and now he can get it...

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted achieve! You read my mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Trying to understand here: In the solution above, is function to_Element() overloaded ? But I had read functions don't become overloaded just by making arguments const in one and non-const in other. How does this particular soln. work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static bool is_Element(const Node *base) {
    const Element *p = NULL; // Add a const keyword here
    p = dynamic_cast<const Element*>(base); // Add a const keyword here
    return (base!=NULL);
}
```

And the same for `to_Element`

Comment: `p` is `Element*` which cannot hold `Element const*`.